# Boot Loop issue

Tags: boot-loop, external-sd

### Summary

<sup>by Izzy</sup>
It seems the SD card in the **LG Marquee** has some errors causing a boot loop once the *Media Scanner* runs (or immediately when it's finished). Taking out the card seems to solve the issue, but then its content cannot be accessed. The original post is...

### TL;DR

I'm a new user and I'm having a terribly annoying problem with my phone. I have an **LG Marquee** with *Boost Mobile*.

A few hours ago, I opened up my gallery and the screen froze, then a force-close option popped up (which happens a lot with this phone so I'm used to it & thought it'd just force-close & then go back to normal as usual). Instead, the screen went blank & the blue icons (home, options, back, search) started flashing.

My phone had restarted completely: I had no service, my wallpaper was blank, etc. My phone does this a lot actually, but will just go back to normal. This time it started up normal, but the SD card icon appeared on my notifications bar & it read "checking SD card for errors". Typically this would occur but then the "Media Scanner is Running" icon would appear & my phone would be fine. The "media scanner running" pop up never appeared, and the blue icons just started flashing again as the screen went blank, only to reboot once again.

My phone kept rebooting itself repeatedly for about an hour every minute or two (making it impossible to make a call or send a text!!) Then I finally just turned it off. Every time it'd reboot, it'd last a couple minutes & the "media scanner running" pop up would come up, then it'd reboot all over again. Seems as though the media scanner triggers the reboot :/

After reading through many posts on the Internet about this issue, I tried a few things. In attempting to fix the problem, I realized that this issue has nothing to do with my phone itself or the battery - it's the SD card. I haven't dropped my phone at all lately and typically refrain from downloading extra apps that I really don't need. Mostly my SD card is taken up by photos, texts, videos, contacts, & three or four extra apps. The last app I downloaded was last night, it was a photo/gallery organizing app. When the reboots started occurring, I quickly uninstalled the app but it didn't fix the problem. The SD card doesn't look physically damaged at all, & neither does the small port it goes in. I use a 2GB micro SD card, the one that came with the phone when I bought it (not the best choice, I know, I just figured I could make due with it).

**I can run my phone perfectly fine** without the impeccably annoying reboots occurring **if I take the SD card out**. The problem is that I obviously need my pictures and videos and other apps, etc. I had quite a few photos and videos, all of which I would be completely devastated and flat out pi**ed off to lose (especially because I had a lot of photos of a close friend that passed away recently in my gallery. Losing those would really make me sooo mad!) All I can do on my phone right now is access the internet, make calls, texts but I have none of my pics/vids & almost none of my apps.

Please help me!! Not only do I want my media and apps back, the constant rebooting is a level of annoying I can't even begin to describe!! I would literally appreciate it so much if someone could help me fix this issue (without having to reformat my SD card and lose everything)': ) and would be forever grateful!! I don't know how you reward/give a thanks to someone that helps you out on here, but I'd happily do it for anyone that can help me fix this problem ASAP. I'm soo unbelievably frustrated, please help me. Thanks so much!

(BTW, my phone is not rooted and none if my photos, videos, or other SD card things are backed up - dumb, I know!! I'm learning my lesson right now, unfortunately)

**UPDATE/EDIT:** I have been trying different tricks and tips from others, nothing has solved the problem but I did notice that the media scanner will actually complete scanning and even load my gallery, apps, etc. and show me that the SD card has been mounted but will automatically reboot all over again by itself about 10 seconds later. It's so frustrating that the card is loading and all my stuff is right there in front of me, but then my phone reboots by itself!

Comment: Please have a look at http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-to-ask-android-questions-the-smart-way. Asking a smart questions will likely help you get a good quality answer. Most people are afraid of reading your question because it's basically a wall of text.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the heads up. I'm a new user and was quite flustered when I posted this. I'll try to edit it or remove the post and create a new one as to avoid confusion.

Comment: I just edited your post, fixed the spelling and formatting, and also added a short summary describing the core of your too long story -- so users don't *have* to read it in full length to figure it out. Additional information needed: Don't you have a PC (or other device) to connect the SDCard to (e.g. via a card reader), so you can copy the contents? In that case the easiest solution seems: Get yourself a new SDCard (at least class 4, better class 6), copy the content there, and use the new card.

Comment: I most cases, editing the question is the better approach

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the edit. I do have a computer but I do not have an SDCard reader. I can acquire one, though. My question is, however (excuse my lack of knowledge w/ this stuff, I'm sure it is elementary to you but I haven't had these problems w/ previous phones so I'm new to it) can I just connect the SDCard I have now to my PC to copy the content I need? Or do I need to get a new card first and somehow transfer the content of the one I have now to the new one? Please explain further if you can, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @Izzy Also, do you think that the problem is my phone or the card? I can't tell b/c my phone works w/o the card inserted, though my phone reboots each time I insert the card & try to scan media. If I can backup my content to my PC, would a factory reset + SDCard reformat be a good option, or should I just buy a new card + factory reset? Sorry for all the questions, I tried talking to Boost Mobile tech service and they weren't helpful at all.

Comment: A factory reset will not be needed I'd say. Copying content to your PC using a card reader (and the other way round) should be an easy thing. Reformatting the card *might* help (worth a try) or not (see Michael's answer below). I'd go for a new (bigger, better) card -- as you already noted the 2G wouldn't be the best option ;)

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the help! Much appreciated. I'll post my results once I give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

Something very similar happened to me not long ago. The SD card, when inserted into the phone, would cause the phone to be very unresponsive and eventually reboot itself, over and over, as long as the card was plugged in.

Now for the bad news.

I inserted a different SD card, which worked just fine in the phone. So I took the malfunctioning SD card and attempted to reformat it on my computer, but after reinserting it into the phone, the phone still claimed it was a "Damaged SD card" and refused to do anything with it - even format it again! Though it did stop boot looping.

After talking with Verizon it seems the SD card really was defective and I'm getting a replacement. I hope you are able to recover some of your files from the card before you have to replace it, or that you have backups (though it sounds like you don't).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do not have any of my files backed up unfortunately. I am going to try buying an SD Card reader and new SD Card and attempt to copy the contents to my PC, then copy the data onto the new card and **hope** that my phone will take the new card & its contents.

Comment: If I am not able to salvage the contents using the process I'm going to try because the card is, in fact, defective I will be very disappointed. Thank you for the heads up, though, so I know what to expect possibly.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's bad news, but even so, the computer _might_ be able to read it. Make sure the card reader you pick up can handle SDHC cards.

Comment: I'm really hoping the computer will be able to read it. What exactly is an SDHC card? My SD card slot says _Micro SD_ right above it, not sure if that makes it any different from other cards.

Comment: SDHC means *Secure Digital High Capacity*. It is just a classification of sdcards. Capacities 4GB above are classified as one. also all phones use micro sd format because of its size. If you are buying, just tell the store clerk that you are looking for a `micro SD` card reader

Comment: Ok great, I'm going to try this and I'll post my results. I appreciate all your help and suggestions!

Comment: Hi. I bought an SD Card and reader yesterday and attempted to copy the files onto my PC. All of the photo and video files display as "Invalid Image." :( These files are very, very important to me. Is there a software I can download that you would recommend that may help me recover my photos(I would be willing to lose the videos if I had to, but not the photos)? I am at my wit's end and am so frustrated and sad :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a somewhat similar experience with a card set up as internal storage (Android Go edition which is slimmed down Oreo), except that I've never seen signs of a "media scanner". The reboots were rare at first and then everything worked fine again; but suddenly it began restarting continuously, during the boot sequence itself, until I pulled out the card.

Managed to resolve it, at least long enough to recover all data, but I'm not sure what the cure was. It might be:

- Rewriting the data on the SD card
- Making Android believe the card is corrupt and then reconciling it
- Just sending the card on an exciting trip, letting circuits discharge or recharge or cool down or heat up

Anyway, the steps one could follow in detail:

1. On a Linux PC with a card reader, find out which device the card is on (`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` where sdX stands for one of sdb, sdc, sdd...)
2. Dump all data to a file with `dd if=/dev/sdX of=my_dump bs=4M` (where dd = data dump, if=input file, of=output file, bs=block size)
3. Probably you can skip everything below until step 11.
4. Wipe the identity and partitioning with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M count=1`
5. Insert the card into the Android device: it now recognizes it as a new, blank card
6. Format the card in Android and eject it.
7. Move the card back to the PC.
8. Restore the first block: `dd if=my_dump of=/dev/sdX bs=4M count=1`
9. Move the card back to the Android device: it now recognizes it as the old internal storage, but says it's corrupt (because it changed other blocks while formatting).
10. Move the card back to the PC.
11. Restore the card entirely: `dd if=my_dump of=/dev/sdX bs=4M`
12. Move the card back to the Android device

Epilogue: Obviously, the rebooting came back, after a few days of normal operation. I repeatedly and in vain tried to repair it with the above procedure, and some variations of it, and it just kept rebooting. But as soon as I restored the earlier contents of the card extracted before posting this (the exact contents it had when the incessant rebooting started), it resumed normal operation. Also, a few weeks later, an identical Micro-SD card of the same age, in a completely unrelated audio device suddenly blocked the machine, then after taking it out a few times resumed as if nothing had happened.